# Format column based on previous columns value

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, boolean, conditional-formatting, boolean-logic

I am trying to format the colours within my google sheet based on the previous columns value. I have tried to implement it with conditional format rules but the results are inconsistent and not reflecting the correct colours.

I have tried to apply a custom formula for positive numbers  `=(D3-C3)>0` and `=(D3-C3)<0` for negative. This results in what is shown in the image. I'm not sure if it is because of the range?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=($D3-$C3)>0
```

and:

```
=($D3-$C3)<0
```

---

### update:

[image]

Comment: This turns all the columns green

Comment: @memyselfandmyiphone can you share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output?

Comment: Cheers. Here is a copy

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CWeQRM0TbnWJdZ_9Imrjb8dWVrbL0dgxcofgqlyp5Z8/edit?usp=sharing

Row 9-10 shows the desired outcome. The formulas are on rows 3-6.

Comment: @memyselfandmyiphone is this it? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hy8Zy9k_vlFenY9xUJCq1XvHGE2qiW7cZBh1XI7qOLg/edit#gid=0

Comment: Not quite. If the number to the right is higher than the number to the left then it should be red. If it is lower, it should be green. For example, in row 3, C3 to E3 should be green and F3 should be red.

Comment: @memyselfandmyiphone see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hy8Zy9k_vlFenY9xUJCq1XvHGE2qiW7cZBh1XI7qOLg/edit#gid=1007058450